# install Erlang 17.3 on Ubuntu 18

Tags: erlang, ubuntu-18.04

I was trying many ways in order to install Erlang 17.3 on Ubuntu 18. So far I came up with this solution you can read below:

Answer (score 0):

For installing older versions of Erlang and working with several at the same time I would recommend using [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl)

If you need more fancy features you could also head for asdf which has a Erlang plugin (which runs kerl under the hood)

Answer (score -1):

For installation Erlang 17.3 on Ubuntu 18 you should do the following things:
Enter in the console next command:

- Download the tar file:

  wget http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_17.3.tar.gz
- Extract the tar file in directory where you download the otp_src_17.3.tar.gz:

  cd '/home/yaroslav/otp_src_17.3'

  tar -zxf otp_src_17.3.tar.gz
- set export ERL_TOP your 'pwd' path:

  export ERL_TOP=`pwd`
- Basic dependencies:

  sudo apt-get install autoconf libncurses-dev build-essential
- Other applications dependencies

  sudo apt-get install m4

  sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

  sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

  sudo apt-get -y install libssh-dev

  sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev libglu-dev

  sudo apt-get install fop xsltproc

  sudo apt-get install g++

  sudo apt-get install default-jdk

  sudo apt-get install xsltproc fop
- Or all dependencies in one line:

  apt-get -y install build-essential autoconf m4 libncurses5-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev libgl1-mesa-
  dev libglu1-mesa-dev libpng-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev xsltproc fop g++ default-jdk
- install openssl version 1.0.2 for Ubuntu 18 (different version SSL is not compatible):

  curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz | tar xz && cd openssl-1.0.2l &&
  sudo ./config && sudo make && sudo make install
- Configure and build:

  ./configure --with-ssl='/home/yaroslav/otp_src_17.3/openssl-1.0.2l'

  sudo make

  sudo make install